# Add extra info about user's bio

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile

I'd like to propose a feature or change, where under user's bio there would be a small-font print about:

- when was the last time this bio was updated,
- whether it is a local bio or the one copied *here* from some other sister SE site.

Why? Well... I've seen *many* bios, that does not correspond to current user's achievements, rep or badges, just because it was written in 2009 and never updated ever since. I'm talking about all that bios, where some developer wrote, that he is just started learning this or that, and to your surprise, you notice, that he or she is already a master in that area, having a lot of tag-gold badges etc.

And adding a footprint about source of a bio is to "resolve" possible doubts, like the one, where for example someone writes about his or her developers career, while in site about planes or history.

**EDIT**: This feature should have also a bit impact on bio's author as well. Seeing date can (in theory?) force you to notice, that you haven't updated your bio *so long ago*, and maybe that you have to do a bit of invalidation to your links there? I seen "so many" bios with no longer working links...

Anyone else finds this small change useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel like this would be a step in something of the wrong direction. It's certainly been said before, but Stack Exchange isn't a social networking site. The bio field is provided as a fun addition so you can learn a bit about the person who's making posts, but ultimately posts should be self-contained, and not dependent on the experience of the poster.

That aside, I guess it could be handy from time to time to see when information was added, but I'm really not sure it would tell anything. Someone might have started working at a company in 2006 (random number, there), wrote that in their bio, and not changed companies since then. Just because something like that is outdated doesn't mean it's wrong, nor, again, should its accuracy actually indicate anything about that person *on Stack Exchange.* It's really up to someone whether they care enough to represent themselves in a current and updated fashion.

Your case of a person saying "I'm just learning this" is a bit different, but my main points still stand: why does it matter? If they post a lot of great content, then great. If they don't, then...not so great. Neither has anything to do with that they indicate that they're new to the technology in their bio.

I'm a bit more confused about your other thought, about whether the bio is copied. My bio is copied everywhere, but that doesn't affect its validity or accuracy on any site. I think it's generally fair to just assume that someone's bio applies wherever they have it apply. If it doesn't, yet again, is that even a problem?

Ultimately, yes, it would be interesting, and sometimes it would resolve a curiosity, but I'm not sure divulging edit dates like that (which could be a privacy violation--I wouldn't consider it one, but some might) or the source of the bio would really be worth it. It seems like it solves a problem that doesn't really (or shouldn't really, at least) exist on a platform like this.

Comment: Please, see my updated question. But, in general, I agree with you. You have shown me a point of view, that I wasn't aware before. Thank you for that.

Comment: @trejder Yeah, for sure. I'm definitely not saying it's a bad idea, it's just that I'm not sure it speaks directly to the goal of Stack Exchange. I hope that makes some sense. But who knows, I could be wrong.